# What is the safest way to pass parameters with defaults in class inheritance?

Tags: python

Suppose I have some Python class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

And now, I want to define a child class whose `y` value is set by default, say with value 1. The only change in this new class is this default for `y`, then I guess this formulation will work

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        y = kwargs.pop("y", 1)
        assert y == 1
        super.__init__(y=y, **kwargs)
```

What is the classic form to pass defaults in inheritance?

Comment: `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): super().__init__(*args, y=1, **kwargs)`…?

Comment: Why not use a regular default argument, `def __init__(self, y=1, **kwargs):`?

Comment: @deceze That effectively *removes* `y` from `B`'s `__init__`. Not at all the same thing as giving it a default value. (If someone tries to pass `y` to `B`, it'll crash because of the duplicate argument.)

Comment: @Aran OP's code throws an error if anyone passes anything other than `1` for `y`. So, `y` is fixed to `1`. So it's useless to have it as parameter at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did that to prevent duplicates

Comment: @deceze Well, true, but I assumed that was just there for demonstration purposes...

Comment: @Aran Which is why this was a comment and not an answer… 

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want. Your current code throws an error if `y` is anything other than `1`, so it's pointless to make it a parameter at all. Just do:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, y=1, **kwargs)
```

This passes all parameters through to `A`, whether passed positionally or as keywords, and fixes `y` to `1`. You'll get an error if you try to pass `y` to `B`.

Alternatively, if you want `y` to *default* to `1` but still be able to supply it as an argument to `B`:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, y=1, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, y=y, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second code sample won't work. It requires keyword arguments which is surprising compared to the first sample and with `assert` it requires `y == 1`, it doesn't default to it. Also `super` must be called.

Usual way (with reordering of parameters) is:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, z, y=1):
        super().__init__(x, y, z)
```

Alternatively without reordering:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, yz, z=None):
        if z is None:
            super().__init__(x, 1, yz)
        else:
            super().__init__(x, yz, z)
```

Comment: I'd refrain from that "no reordering" method. It just makes the API needlessly complex. And since it's another class entirely, the constructor doesn't typically require API compatibility with the parent class.